# Purity of Kohanim

Tags: kohen-priest, beis-hamikdash, korban, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, birchas-kohanim

If (theoretically) the great Temple was built again, would there be Kohanim pure enough (physically, etc.) to perform the worship and sacrifices?

Comment: What do you mean by 'pure enough'? Pure/impure is generally viewed as a spiritual state, yet in your parenthesis you write 'physically, etc'. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Why do you ask about "[i]f (theoretically) the great Temple [were] built again"? Why isn't that a practicality?

Comment: @msh i think he means were it built now

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40106/kohanim-and-the-third-temple

Comment: @DoubleAA you are correct--I meant if it was built today.  Pure is spiritual, but it is also physical, based on a few material things mentioned below. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

[The Raavad to Hilchos Nezirus 5(15)](http://www.daat.ac.il/he-il/toshba/rambam/haplaa/nezirut/nezirut5.htm?printview=true) states that

> הכהנים בזמן הזה טמאי מת הן 
>   Kohanim in our time are impure with טומאת
>   מת.

So, no there would not be Kohanim pure enough (physically, etc.) to ideally perform the worship and all the sacrifices.

But when all or most of the community are  impure from contact with the dead, sacrifices with a fixed time are permitted [טומאה הותרה בציבור](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%94_%D7%94%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8), so in effect they would be pure enough for a great portion of the Temple service.

Comment: They can do the avoda while impure from a corpse...

Comment: I edited the answer to take account of DoubleAA's comment.

Comment: Incidentally the raavad was talking about kohanim in his day and it's not clear he'd think we are all vadai temei met since nowadays people usually die in hospitals, not at home.

Comment: But even kohanim who are taamei met can purify themselves using the ashes from the red heifer

Comment: @mbl if they have it then yes. But if the mikdash just appears in 5 minutes from now, we'll be in business right away, as far as purity of Kohanim is concerned. We won't have to wait a week to apply the ashes (assuming any are available)